# How do I handle unknown attributes in a configuration file

Tags: .net

In our application, we have a custom configuration that we save and read. Our problem is this: as the product evolves, some configuration properties are no longer needed, or are renamed, or whatever. Files written by previous versions of our product have these properties in them, so when these files are read an exception is thrown (ConfigurationErrorsException).

Is there any way to catch the exception so that the unknown property is ignored?

Here is an example of what I mean. If I try to read the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="MySettings" type="Config.MySettingsConfiguration, Config, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" overrideModeDefault="Allow" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="true" />
    </configSections>
    <MySettings>
        <MyElement Bogus=""/>
    </MySettings>
</configuration>
```

and "Bogus" is not defined as a property of "MyElement", an exception will be thrown. I would like to be able to catch this exception and ignore "Bogus" (or not have the exception thrown at all).

Thanks!

JAB

Comment: How are you reading and parsing this document? Is the exception unhandled? Please post the C#/VB.NET code that handles this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the fact that this proves to be a problem, means your deployment practices aren't good. You should not have residual, deprecated configuration values in the config files of your deployed applications. Prepare to do configuration transforms and deploy your software including configuration files and the problem will go away.

However, you can prevent the exception from being thrown and continue parsing.

From [Creating Configuration Sections – P3.NET](http://blogs.msmvps.com/p3net/2010/03/07/creating-configuration-sections/):

> Configuration elements/sections expose two overridable methods (OnDeserializeUnrecognizedAttribute and OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement) that are called if the parse finds an unknown element/attribute during parsing.  These methods can be used to support simple dynamic parsing.
>
> For unknown attributes the method gets the name and value that was parsed.  If the method returns true then the subsystem assumes the attribute was handled otherwise an exception is thrown.

So override [`ConfigurationElement.OnDeserializeUnrecognizedAttribute Method (String, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement.ondeserializeunrecognizedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `MySettings : ConfigurationElement` class and return `true` when you know the attribute for which it was called is deprecated.

So something like this:

```
public class MySettings : ConfigurationElement
{
    private string[] _deprecatedAttributes = new[] { "foo", "bar" };
    
    protected override bool OnDeserializeUnrecognizedAttribute(string attribute, string value)
    {
        if (_deprecatedAttributes.Contains(attribute))
        {
            return true;
        }
        
        return base.OnDeserializeUnrecognizedAttribute(attribute, value);
    }
}
```

You do need that check and you can't just `return true` for all attributes, as that will break validation for attributes that are really invalid and never were valid.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because it solved my problem. But I was amused by your assertion that our "deployment practices aren't good". What we do may be unconventional, but the file in question is not deployed. It is created when our application is first run, and written by the application. Consequently, when a new version of our application is released, there may be some attributes or elements that have changed, which is why I needed to know how to handle them. Thanks for your response.